# should batch_writer in dynamodb be super fatser?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a weired results on uploading 17,956,000,000 records into dynamodb. Thos records are on 134,000 files (and each file have a 134,000 record). If you ask about those records, its a full city distance matrix (the city has 134,000 nodes). To do so, i have uploaded all files into s3 pucket. Also, I have tried a lambda python function to do a sqs queue later. When measure a single file uploading time (from s3 to dynamodb using lambda python function), i couldn't upload a full file withing 15 min (max exec time on lambda). I did some tests comparing the batch write with a 3 minutes execution as:

```
with table.batch_writer() as bw:
  for k, v in obj.items():
    bw.put_item(Item={"_from":src_node,"_to":dst_node,"travel_time":v})
```

which got to upload a total of 2,475 records.

```
for k, v in obj.items():
  dynamodb.put_item(TableName='xxx', Item={"_from":{"N":src_node},"_to":{'N':dst_node},"travel_time":{"N":str(v)}})
```

which got to upload a total of 2,404 records.

I wan't to validate if those results are logical or something should be wrong.

Comment: What is the configured WCU (Write Capacity Units) for your table? Have you calculated how many WCU you'll need for the amount of data that you're uploading?

Comment: For that matter, have you calculated how much you'll be paying to store this data? You might be in for an unwelcome surprise at the end of the month.

Comment: Write capacity aside, you may also find that configuring a larger RAM size of the Lambda helps. That said, for a one-time or infrequent (I'm guessing?) ingestion into DynamoDB, Lambda does not seem to be the best choice. Blog post on [Implementing bulk CSV ingestion to Amazon DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/implementing-bulk-csv-ingestion-to-amazon-dynamodb/) in case it's helpful.